# How to send message from Jersey @POST method to client-side AJAX?

Tags: post, jersey

I have the following Java method that is annotated as Jersey @POST to handle form submission:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("created")
public Response createCustomer(@FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("dob") Date dob)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    URI uri = URI.create(uriInfo.getPath());
    Response r;
    Integer id;

    try {
        id = dbController.create(username, name, dob); // This may throw exception.
        r = Response.created(uri).build();


    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        String errMsg = ex.getMessage();
        // To do: how to send error message to AJAX so that client-side can see the error message?

    }

    return r;
}
```

After form submission, if there are some errors, I want the client-side user to see the error message sent from backend REST service. How to write the code in order to send message from backend to frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add something like

```
return Response.status(400).entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
```

or of course

```
r = Response.status(400).entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
```

to your catch block. (Status-code depending on what you want to say, of course.)

Comment: Thanks Andreas. So does that `entity()` method send its argument to the client-side and client-side can receive the error message from that?

Comment: Right. It adds it to the body of the response, so you should have no difficulties to use it in the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an error code like the following:

```
return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the response in your own object, like that:

```
public class MyResponse {
    private boolean success = true;
    private String exMessage;
    private Object data;
    ...
}
```

Then you just add the data you want to serialize to Json as the MyResponse.setData(). In case it fails, you set success to false and set the exMessage. Just create an envelop of your own that allows you to append any information you need to the data you are sending.

EDIT: Compared to the selected answer, this doesn't make you parse different ways when it's an error.

Comment: Thanks. If I do in this way, should I inherit MyResponse class from Response class since I want to use it in the @POST method, which returns a Response object?

Comment: Nope, it's meant to be inserted into the Response class. It is meant as a wrapper to the data. It isn't meant to inherit Response class, sorry if the name suggests it.